# PHP shell_exec to run debian system service

Tags: debian, sudo, php, exec

I'm trying to control a system service with PHP's `shell_exec` function :

```
shell_exec('sudo /usr/sbin/service icecast2 stop');
```

But the only way I can get it to work is by allowing ALL users root access to the services in `/etc/sudoers` :

```
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

This is obviously a really bad idea, but it refuses to run if I try to set it to anything else as the service needs root privs eg :

```
%www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

Also an echo of `posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];` gives me a different name that is running the process - not www-data. But neither of these work either :

```
%myphpuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
%myphpuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

I also tried writing a bash script to control the service and call it from shell_exec, but that fails to run to.

Can anybody think of any other solution so I don't leave my services open like this?

For instance, just allowing access to this specific service and function instead?

**EDIT**

Made some progress. This works, but is this safe enough?

```
myphpuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myphpuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

Should also mention that the php script that calls this is run by a cron job, it's not public facing in anyway whatsoever.

Comment: You say “it refuses to run”, “neither of these work either” and “that fails to run [too]”.  Please be more specific about what happened. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: consider narrowing down the (eventual) sudo rules down to `usr/sbin/service icecast2 stop` and `usr/sbin/service icecast2 start` (so that a PHP user can't stop arbitrary services)

Comment: I think your initial problem was using `%foo` ; the `%` means "group", so you were looking for the _group_ "myphpuser" and not the user.

Comment: Yes I realised that on my travels after posting this question. Thanks for clarifying though.